# Error in suplibOsInit

Tags: command-line, kernel, virtualbox

I recently downloaded Virtualbox. These are the steps I took:

1. I first went to VirtualBox download and downloaded the right version for my computer and OS (Ubuntu 16.04 64bit).
2. I opened up my terminal and went into the Downloads directory. I continued to type ls to open what was in my downloads file. The only thing in there was the Virtualbox file
3. I copied the file link and before I pasted it I typed "sudo dpkg  -i" and the copied the link after.

This finally got everything installed. Finally I opened up Virtualbox and I made my windows virtual machine correctly, and I tried to start it, but it came up with a Error in **suplibOsInit**. I read this and it says I need to reinstall the kernel module by executing `/sbin/vboxconfig` Could someone please tell me how to fix this problem.

After running the 'sudo apt list virtual* the output was:

```
Listing... Done
virtualbox/xenial-updates 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 amd64
virtualbox-5.2/now 5.2.6-120293~Ubuntu~xenial amd64 [installed,local]
virtualbox-dbg/xenial-updates 5.0.18-dfsg-2ubuntu1 amd64
virtualbox-dkms/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 all
virtualbox-ext-pack/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 5.0.40-0ubuntu1.16.04.1 all
virtualbox-guest-additions-iso/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 5.0.40-0ubuntu1.16.04.1 all
virtualbox-guest-dkms/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 all
virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1~16.04.4 all
virtualbox-guest-source/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 all
virtualbox-guest-source-hwe/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1~16.04.4 all
virtualbox-guest-utils/xenial-updates 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 amd64
virtualbox-guest-utils-hwe/xenial-updates 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1~16.04.4 amd64
virtualbox-guest-x11/xenial-updates 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 amd64
virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe/xenial-updates 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1~16.04.4 amd64
virtualbox-qt/xenial-updates,now 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 amd64 [residual-config]
virtualbox-source/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 all
virtualbricks/xenial,xenial 1.0.2-1 all
virtualenv/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 15.0.1+ds-3ubuntu1 all
virtualenv-clone/xenial,xenial 0.2.5-1 all
virtualenvwrapper/xenial,xenial 4.3.1-2 all
virtualjaguar/xenial 2.1.2-2 amd64
```

Comment: I may have read your question backwards when I answered earlier on your question - what is the host operating system that you are using?

Comment: If I understand your question right, I have Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit) and I downloaded the Virtualbox AMD64 under Ubuntu 16.04 ("Xenial") If this does not answer your question, please direct me on how to find my host operating system.

Comment: I was a little confused by your statement that you 'ran it as root' - root is generally disabled in Ubuntu systems, and sudo is used to run commands with the root permissions.  I'd like to ask you to run two commands, to make sure some needed elements are present on your system.  The first is `uname -a` to we can tell what kernel you are using, and the second is `apt list build-essential, linux-headers-$(uname -r)
` to show system components required to compile some of the vbox modules are present.

Comment: Additionally, if you could run `apt list virtual*` that would help - you can copy and paste the output of these commands into your question....

Comment: These are my results after running the commands: After I ran 'uname -a' 
Linux ASUS 4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 After I ran 'sudo apt list build-essential 
Listing... Done
build-essential/xenial,now 12.1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
jwava@ASUS:~$ sudo apt list build-essential, linux-headers

he result after I ran 'sudo apt list build-essential, linux-headers-$(uname -r)'

Listing... Done
linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Comment: I also did the 'sudo apt list virtual*' command:

Comment: K - it's better to edit your question and append the outputs into the question - I'd like to see what the output of `sudo apt list virtual*` is...

Comment: OK i added the output of that command to my question.

Comment: Thanks.  Aside from the 'There were problems setting up VirtualBox', were there any additional parts of the error message?  [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852590/failed-installation-of-virtualbox-5-1-on-ubuntu-16-04) shows a more complete output of that type of error message, and instructed that user to examine 'dmesg' for further output.

Comment: Well, I just opened VirtualBox in my terminal and this was the message that popped up WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
  Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
  headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

  You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.

Comment: K - two questions:  1)  Did you have a version fo virtualbox installed prior to this and 2)  Do you have secure boot enabled?

Comment: No I do not have a previous version of Virtualbox before this. I checked my systems bootingaptions and I have Boot0000* Ubuntu and Boot0001* which is UEFI.

Comment: Secureboot is somewhat separate from UEFI - I have read in other posts, that some kernel modules do not seem to compile and install correctly if secure boot is enabled.

Comment: OK then, could you guide me through how to disable seure boot?

Comment: Its a BIOS setting in the computer - how to access the BIOS will be different in each manufacturer's system - there is some information at [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Disabling_SecureBoot_in_the_BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Disabling_SecureBoot_in_the_BIOS)

Comment: Ok I disabled the secure boot and I will see if it works!

Comment: You will probably need to re-run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`

Comment: OK I will run it and see what happens

Comment: How did it work out?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty easy process:

Open a terminal window (press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

Enter the command

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

It takes a few minutes to finish

Enter the command `exit` to close the terminal window

Comment: I did the command line and after a few minutes I got this response 
"There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.    So I ran this code again as root and the same error popped up