# Linux 4.15.0-99-generic with Ubuntu18.04 and VirtualBox

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I'm experiencing some issues when using VirtualBox with Ubuntu 18.04 and Linux 4.15.0-99-generic kernel as Host. When trying to start my Windows guest I get prompted with the following error:

```
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing


'/sbin/vboxconfig'


as root.


If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.


where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

I have secure boot disabled and executing '/sbin/vboxconfig' fails with the following logs:

```
Building the main VirtualBox module.
Error building the module:
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-99-generic/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j8 modules
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
/opt/gcc-9.2.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/opt/gcc-9.2.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPDrv-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/gcc-9.2.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/includ$
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/gcc-9.2.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./a$
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrvGip.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/gcc-9.2.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I$
/opt/gcc-9.2.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrvSem.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/gcc-9.2.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I$
/opt/gcc-9.2.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPLibAll.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/gcc-9.2.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I$
/opt/gcc-9.2.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrvTracer.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/gcc-9.2.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi$
/opt/gcc-9.2.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/.alloc-r0drv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/gcc-9.2.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include$
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.o] Error 1
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/.initterm-r0drv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/gcc-9.2.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/incl$
/opt/gcc-9.2.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/opt/gcc-9.2.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/opt/gcc-9.2.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvSem.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvSem.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.o] Error 1
/opt/gcc-9.2.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.1/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/SUPLibAll.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/SUPLibAll.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o] Error 1
Makefile:1577: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/vbox.0' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile-footer.gmk:114: recipe for target 'vboxdrv' failed
```

I have:

- Reinstalled VirtualBox,
- Tried several different versions of VirtualBox (Latest, test, Ubuntu repo etc),
- Reinstalled dkms, virtualbox-dkms and headers,
- Tried installing the shared libraries,
- Updated my system.

**All without success.**

Has anyone else experienced this issue? I'm running out of ideas here. This started after I rebooted my system after having it running over several system updates.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: `error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` You're clearly missing required libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed installation of Virtualbox 5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852590/failed-installation-of-virtualbox-5-1-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @Pilot6 I clearly state I have Secure Boot disable. Ken, I have tried installing these libs without success. karel Thanks for the link. I have already went through this without success I'm afraid.

Comment: _How_ did installing the required libs not succeed? Did you get any errors? Please [edit] your question to include all details.

Answer (score 1):

That is an old kernel! Anyway, the message suggests you miss `libisl.so.21`, which is doubly puzzling to me, as

- it is a dependency of the compiler, so you *should* have it
- as a shared library, it has no business being in a kernel module

However, the compiler you build it (`gcc-9.2.1`) is actually quite new, and since you need to compile kernel modules with the same compiler as the kernel and your kernel was compiled with `gcc-7`, I would suggest trying

```
CC=gcc-7 /sbin/vboxconfig
```

Of course you need gcc-7 installed. Please post the log if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. It seems to produce the same set of error logs I'm afraid. Still complaining about the same shared libraries.

Comment: Did it use gcc-7?